# What is the anticipated time frame for upcoming small site elections?

Tags: support, election, company

Background:

As I understand it, running elections is labor intensive.  There was/is a plan in the works to make them less so, enabling multiple sites to run elections simultaneously.  Example -- ([comment](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2130/congratulations-youre-no-longer-in-beta/2133#comment5571_2133) by @Catija): "one of the things that's supposed to happen this year is an automated elections process that will make it much easier for us to run many elections simultaneously."

However, @Catija [recently wrote](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2292/what-is-the-status-of-the-increase-in-repuation-thresholds-for-privileges/2299#comment6188_2299)

> Shog was the one building the new election system so I don’t know what we’re doing right now though I’ve been told it’s a priority. For most things that require changing site settings, it’s a matter of a few factors - whether we customize it, if there’s a demonstrated need, if we have time to review requests. A great many things are possible.

### Dear Stack Exchange,

Can you give the community an approximate idea of the target date range for small sites' moderator elections?  Is it safe to say there will be no small site elections in February?  Are they unlikely to occur in March as well?

Will the Community Management Team be taking the initiative to run elections at Writing, which currently has zero active moderators?

In the case of small sites that have only one or two moderators, will it be up to the existing moderator(s) to request an election?

Comment: Just FYI: a recent request asking for "emergency" moderator elections was heavily downvoted and deleted.

Comment: I'd say vote. If someone has the courage and ability to stand up, support them. Its worth considering though, for some reason, the community management team is *smaller than many full sized mod teams* despite all the lovely noises from management about the community mattering. Pressure and timeframes... are tricky when you don't know what's happening next.

Comment: @Sonic - do you mean here at Meta SE?  Hmm.  I wonder why it was deleted?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek - Well, whether to vote or not might be an interesting discussion -- in response to a question that poses that question.  I only mentioned it as background motivation for my question, which is intended as a query for management. // What you said about the size of the CM team is interesting.  I know we have lost three team members.  How many are left in the team at present, actually?  And is there some way that plain community members (like me) can see this number publicly?

Comment: I think it's about 3+2 and that's mostly guesswork

Comment: @JourneymanGeek - Thank you.  What is "3+2"?  (Other than the sum, 5.)

Comment: 3 people designated as CMs, 2 others involved as far as I know

Comment: @JourneymanGeek - Very interesting.  Let's see, I know these names: Juan, Cesar, Tim Post, Catija.  I wonder, were the two brought over recently?  Perhaps to handle all the tension of the past four+ months?  Or to cope with the three recent losses? // Do you know why the question Sonic mentioned was deleted?

Comment: you forgot jnat. Juan's in charge overall. I don't think Tim's been a ground level CM a while, since he joked about being demoted to management before. I think I forgot Nicholas, but he's more on the international sites.

Comment: For seeing who is in the team: [Who are the Community Team, and what do they do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/99341/352819) For automating graduations: [Congratulations, you're no longer in Beta!](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2130/congratulations-youre-no-longer-in-beta/2133#comment5571_2133)

Comment: @SecSE- Thanks, I added something from the second link. // First link -- very nice.  It's been updated.